# UIPopoverPresentationController does not call UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate methods

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, delegates, popover

I tried to present popover on iPad via `UIPopoverPresentationController`. Everything just fine but seem no method of `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate` is called.

```
AddRewardController *addRewardVC = [[AddRewardController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddRewardController" bundle:nil];
addRewardVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
addRewardVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 255);

UIPopoverPresentationController *popVC = addRewardVC.popoverPresentationController;
popVC.delegate = self;
popVC.sourceView = self.view;;
popVC.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y, 1.0f, 1.0f); // present in center of view
popVC.permittedArrowDirections = 0; //I dont want to show arrow so i set it to 0

[self presentViewController:addRewardVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

My view controller implement both `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate` and `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate`

I implement `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate`  delegate like this (but none of them is called)

```
- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller {
    return UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
}

- (UIViewController *)presentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle:(UIModalPresentationStyle)style {
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller.presentedViewController];
    return navController;
}
```

Did i do something wrong and why it not call my delegate method?

Comment: For me the problem was that, calling the PopoverViewController through a "PerformSegue" was always ignoring the delegates. Deleting the storyboard segue and manually assembling it and showing through presentViewController solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Use this delegate method: -

```
(UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller traitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)traitCollection;
```

The method you are implementing works for iPhone only.